# Buffer or string or array for adding chunks with json

Tags: node.js

I'm downloading varying sizes of json data from a provider. The sizes can vary from a couple of hundred bytes to tens of MB.

Got into trouble with a string (i.e. stringVar += chunk). I'm not sure, but I suspect my crashes has to to with quite large strings (15 MB).

In the end I need the json data. My temporary solution is to use a string up to 1MB and then "flushing" it to a buffer. I didn't want to use a buffer from start as it would have to be grown (i.e. copied to a larger buffer) quite often when downloads are small.

Which solution is the best for concatenating downloaded chunks and then parsing to json?

1.

```
var dataAsAString = '';
..
dataAsAString += chunk;
..
JSON.parse(dataAsAString);
```

2.

```
var dataAsAnArray = [];
..
dataAsAnArray.push(chunk);
..
concatenate
JSON.parse..
```

3.

```
var buffer = new Buffer(initialSize)
..
buffer.write(chunk)
..
copy buffer to larger buffer when needed
..
JSON.parse(buffer.toString());
```

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are appending the chunk in a cumulative manner.

If you could store the necessary metadata for the entire duration of all data processing, then you could use a loop and just process the chunk. chunk data should be declared in the loop, then after every iteration, the chunk variable goes out of scope and used memory wouldn't grow  continuously.

```
while((chunk=receiveChunkedData())!=null)
{
 JSON.parse(chunk);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Excuse me, I'm quite new to http.get. But I wonder, how can JSON.parse cope with small chunks that one by one won't describe a valid json object?

Comment: Tried it. As I suspected this is not a way forward. JSON.parse gets confused when thrown small chunks of strings that don't represent valid json.

Comment: thats why I said, the metadata is also required to along with each chunk to make it valid JSON.

Comment: Ah, ok. But I have no clue of what json structure I will get when I download. I suppose there exists some kind of json parser that can handle stream data. But since it's very rare that I get data bigger than 1-2 MB this seems like overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I have now moved to streams instead of accumulating buffers. Streams are really awesome.

If someone comes here for a solution on accumulating buffer chunks in a speedy manner I thought I'd share my find..

Substack has a module for keeping all the chunks separate without reallocating memory and then treat them as a contiguous buffer when you need.

https://github.com/substack/node-buffers

Answer (score 0):

I think [node-stream-buffer](https://github.com/samcday/node-stream-buffer) can solve your problem.